# SonarQube Architecture Rule Engine for C#

Tags: c#, .net, sonarqube

SonarQube has a Java only Architecture Rule Engine. I am looking for a way to implement similar reference architecture rules for C# .net project.

For example:

- Forbid access to `*.A.*` from `*.B.*` classes
- Enforce at least one access to `*.A.*` from `*.C.*` classes.

What would be the best way to implement this ? 
Is it possible to create these rules in FXCop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the long term, we definitely want to provide such a rule out of the box with the C# SonarQube plugin.

However, in the meantime, you could indeed either develop your own custom FxCop rule (which are supported by the existing C# SonarQube plugin), or, develop a new SonarQube plugin to import issues from an unsupported tool such as Nitriq as suggested.

Feel free to look at the R# plugin and send requests to the SonarQube development mailing list if you need any help on that:
https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-resharper

Answer (score 0):

You can create the rules with [Nitriq](http://nitriq.com/):

**Forbid access to *.A.* from *.B.* classes**

```
var results = 
from t in Types
where t.Name.Equals("A") && t.TypesUsing.Any("B")
select new { t.TypeId, t.Name, t.FullName };
Warn(results, 0);
```

**Enforce at least one access to *.A.* from *.C.* classes.**

```
var results = 
from t in Types
where t.Name.Equals("A") && !t.TypesUsing.Any("C")
select new { t.TypeId, t.Name, t.FullName };
Warn(results, 0);
```

Another approach is use [Roslyn](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/)